# Настроить шорткат в vs community 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Допустим я инициализирую поле

```
public string Label
```

Как мне назначить шорткат(Допустим  Ctrl+G,P), чтобы автоматически дописать

```
{ get; protected set; }
```

И в итоге получилось

```
public int Price { get; protected set; }
```

Comment: [Code snippets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Можно просто написать `prop`+`Tab`  и получится почти то, что вам надо. Вдруг вы не в курсе.